# NullReferenceException after AddJsonBody

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

[RestSharp 105.2.3]

Using AddJsonBody, I end up with a request carrying a Parameters object with one item reading

```
[1] = {={"id":"100007988",[...]}}
```

Executing this request, a NullReferenceException is thrown.

If I use

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", contentJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

instead, the Parameters item reads like this

```
[1] = {application/json={"id":"100007988",[...]}}
```

Executing this request succeeds.

Unfortunately, the latter variant requires me to serialize the Json object explicitly while the other uses the ISerializer which has been declared as a handler for "application/json".

Do I miss something or is this a (pretty basic) bug in RestSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look into the sources, I found that I was missing to set the ContentType property in my ISerialize implementation. This is used to set the name of the parameter.

So, just added a constructor for my ISerialize implementation stating

```
this.ContentType = "application/json";
```

did the trick.